# Vba on Mac ScrollBar allows only double-clicking

Tags: excel, macos, vba, scroll

I have found the very strange situation on Mac Excel. For some strange reason the scrollbars react on double-click but not click and mouse-down.
To test it, I created the blank form and added that code to the form initialize:
`UserForm1.ScrollBars=MsForms.fmScrollBarsBoth`
`UserForm1.ScrollWidth=900`
`UserForm1.ScrollHeight=900`

Then run it and found that scrollbars reacting only double-click&move.

Who can help me with it?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with the built in scroll bars on my mac 2011 version. I had to improvise by creating my own scroll bar with a picture to give it a background, a text box for the button (I had to make the text box very narrow to get rid of the cursor blinking issue - mouse controls will work only with a couple of controls & the only one that worked for this purpose was the textbox) I then had to use 10 labels within the range of the picture, programmatically position them and make them invisible but still there.. I had to do this to allow the user to jump to various spots within the scroll bar by using the click event on the labels.  Then I had to add the arrow buttons on the top and bottom of the picture to make it look and feel like a scroll bar. It took me most of a day to figure out all the code. I had it record all the present location data for each item on the form so that way it could remember the default locations for each object and then as the scroll bar moves from its default location all the other object move equally in the opposite direction.. All this was a royal pain.. it works well but fact is, microsoft should be able to program their form controls to do their functions properly and we shouldn't have to do all this otherwise work to get around microsofts mistakes in programming..  Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

This might help...
Here was my code for my vertical scrollbar workaround for mac 2011:

```
Public ScrollPosition, MaxScroll As Long
Public TrueBottomScroll As Double
Public ButtonScroll, ScrollUpDown As Boolean
Dim xOffset As Single
Dim yOffset As Single
Public RelativeTop As Double
Public ButtonResize As Boolean
Dim cmdArray() As New Class1

'Scroll Left to Right (ctrlMoveMe):

Public BtnMoveMe As Boolean
Public ScrollLeftRight As Boolean
Dim MoveMe_xOffset As Single
Public MoveMe_MaxScroll As Long

Function ScrollPos(y As Long)

Dim cCont As Control
Dim ScrollRate, r, h As Long
Dim CtrlName As String

 If ScrollUpDown = True Then ButtonScroll = True

 ScrollBottom = ScrollBar1.Top + ScrollBar1.Height
MaxScroll = ScrollBottom - ScrollButton.Height

   If ButtonScroll = True Then
        If ScrollButton.Top + y < 28 Then
            ScrollButton.Top = 28
        ElseIf ScrollButton.Top + y > MaxScroll Then
            ScrollButton.Top = MaxScroll - 4
        Else
            ScrollButton.Top = (ScrollButton.Top + y)
        End If
    End If

TrueBottomScroll = Application.Max(Range("B:B"))
r = Application.Match(TrueBottomScroll, Range("B:B"), 0)
CtrlName = Range("A" & r)
h = Me.Controls(CtrlName).Height
TrueBottomScroll = TrueBottomScroll + h
'MsgBox TrueBottomScroll

ScrollRate = TrueBottomScroll / MaxScroll

ScrollPosition = (ScrollButton.Top - 28) * ScrollRate


Dim OriginalPos As Long
    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If cCont.name = "ScrollButton" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBar1" _
            Or cCont.name = "cmdScrollUp" _
            Or cCont.name = "cmdScrollDown" _
            Or cCont.name = "ctrResizeWindow" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump1" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump2" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump3" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump4" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump5" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump6" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump7" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump8" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump9" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump10" Then
        Else
            OriginalPos = Application.Index(Range("A:B"), Application.Match(cCont.name, Range("A:A"), 0), 2)
            cCont.Top = OriginalPos - ScrollPosition
        End If
    Next cCont
    If ScrollUpDown = True Then
    ScrollUpDown = False
    ButtonScroll = False
    End If
End Function



Private Sub cmdScrollUp_Click()
ScrollUpDown = True
    ScrollPos (-35)
End Sub
Private Sub cmdScrollDown_Click()
ScrollUpDown = True
    ScrollPos (35)
End Sub


Private Sub ctrl_MoveMe_Click()
BtnMoveMe = True
ScrollLeftRight = True
MoveMe_ScrollPos (x)
End Sub

Private Sub ctrl_MoveMe_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
BtnMoveMe = True
End Sub

Private Sub ctrlMoveMe_Enter()
BtnMoveMe = True
End Sub
Private Sub ctrlMoveMe_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
If BtnMoveMe = True Then Me.ctrlMoveMe.Left = Me.ctrlMoveMe.Left + x

' If BtnMoveMe = True Then MoveMe_ScrollPos (x)
End Sub
Private Sub ctrlMoveMe_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
BtnMoveMe = False
End Sub





Private Sub ScrollBarJump1_Click()
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + 5
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBarJump2_Click()
n = 2
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBarJump3_Click()
n = 3
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBarJump4_Click()
n = 4
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub
Private Sub ScrollBarJump5_Click()
n = 5
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub
Private Sub ScrollBarJump6_Click()
n = 6
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub
Private Sub ScrollBarJump7_Click()
n = 7
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub
Private Sub ScrollBarJump8_Click()
n = 8
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub
Private Sub ScrollBarJump9_Click()
n = 9
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub
Private Sub ScrollBarJump10_Click()
n = 10
Me.ScrollButton.Top = Me.ScrollBar1.Top + ((Me.ScrollBar1.Height / 10) * n) - (Me.ScrollButton.Height * (0.1 * n))
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollButton_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
       ButtonScroll = True
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollButton_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
 ScrollPos (y)
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollButton_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
    ButtonScroll = False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
DisableEvents
Me.Width = 500

Dim ScrollBottom, r, NewWidth, n, NewLeft As Long
NewWidth = 15
NewLeft = Me.Width - NewWidth - 5

'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Scroll Jump:
For n = 1 To 10
    With Me.Controls("ScrollBarJump" & n)
        .Height = ScrollBar1.Height / 10
        .Top = 30 + (.Height * (n - 1))
        .Left = NewLeft + 3
        .Width = NewWidth - 7.5
        .Caption = ""
    End With
Next
''''''''''''''''''''''

 With ctrResizeWindow
        .Width = 10
        .Left = Me.Width - .Width
        .Height = 10
        .Top = Me.Height - 22 - .Height
    End With

    ''''''' End ResizeWindow --> Begin Vertical ScrollBar''''''''



    With ScrollButton
        .Height = 40
        .Top = 30
        .Left = NewLeft + 3
        .Width = NewWidth - 7.5
        .ZOrder msoBringToFront
    End With

    With ScrollBar1
        .Height = Me.Height - 74
        .Top = .Top
        .Left = NewLeft
        .Width = NewWidth
    End With

    With cmdScrollUp
    .Height = .Height
        .Top = .Top
        .Left = NewLeft
        .Width = NewWidth
    End With

    With cmdScrollDown
    .Height = .Height
        .Top = ScrollBar1.Top + ScrollBar1.Height
        .Left = NewLeft
        .Width = NewWidth
    End With


ScrollBottom = ScrollBar1.Top + ScrollBar1.Height
MaxScroll = ScrollBottom - ScrollButton.Height
ScrollPosition = ScrollButton.Top - 28


On Error GoTo SheetExists
Sheets.Add.name = "ScrollBarData"
EditSheet:
On Error GoTo 0
Sheets("ScrollBarData").Activate

r = 1
    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If cCont.name = "ScrollButton" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBar1" _
            Or cCont.name = "cmdScrollUp" _
            Or cCont.name = "cmdScrollDown" _
            Or cCont.name = "ctrResizeWindow" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump1" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump2" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump3" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump4" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump5" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump6" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump7" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump8" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump9" _
            Or cCont.name = "ScrollBarJump10" Then
        Else
            Cells(r, 1) = cCont.name
            Cells(r, 2) = cCont.Top
            r = r + 1
        End If

    Next cCont

    Exit Sub

SheetExists:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'MsgBox ActiveSheet.name
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    GoTo EditSheet
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
EnableEvents
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Sheets("ScrollBarData").Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



Private Sub ctrResizeWindow_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
        If x > 0 Then xOffset = Me.Width - (ctrResizeWindow.Left + x)
        If y > 0 Then yOffset = Me.Height - (ctrResizeWindow.Top + y)

        ScrollBottom = ScrollBar1.Top + ScrollBar1.Height
       MaxScroll = ScrollBottom - ScrollButton.Height
       If RelativeTop = 0 Then
            RelativeTop = ScrollButton.Top / MaxScroll
       End If
   ButtonResize = True
End Sub

Private Sub ctrResizeWindow_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
   Dim FormHeight, ResizeMin As Integer
  ResizeMin = 30


   If ButtonResize = True Then
    If (ctrResizeWindow.Left + x) + xOffset < ResizeMin + 100 Then GoTo WindowIsNarrow
        Me.Width = (ctrResizeWindow.Left + x) + xOffset
WindowIsNarrow:
        ctrResizeWindow.Left = Me.Width - ctrResizeWindow.Width
                If (ctrResizeWindow.Top + y) + yOffset < ResizeMin + 100 Then GoTo WindowIsSmall
        Me.Height = (ctrResizeWindow.Top + y) + yOffset
        ctrResizeWindow.Top = Me.Height - 22 - ctrResizeWindow.Height
WindowIsSmall:
        Dim ScrollBottom, r, NewLeft, NewWidth As Long


NewWidth = 15
NewLeft = Me.Width - NewWidth - 5

 FormHeight = Me.Height - 74
  If FormHeight < ResizeMin Then Exit Sub



    With ScrollBar1
        .Height = Me.Height - 74
        .Top = .Top
        .Left = NewLeft
        .Width = NewWidth
    End With

    With cmdScrollUp
    .Height = .Height
        .Top = .Top
        .Left = NewLeft
        .Width = NewWidth
    End With

    With cmdScrollDown
    .Height = .Height
        .Top = ScrollBar1.Top + ScrollBar1.Height
        .Left = NewLeft
        .Width = NewWidth
    End With

    ScrollBottom = ScrollBar1.Top + ScrollBar1.Height
    MaxScroll = ScrollBottom - ScrollButton.Height
   ' End If
        With ScrollButton
        .Height = 40
        .Top = MaxScroll * RelativeTop
        .Left = NewLeft + 3
        .Width = NewWidth - 7.5
    End With


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Scroll Jump:
For n = 1 To 10
    With Me.Controls("ScrollBarJump" & n)
        .Height = ScrollBar1.Height / 10
        .Top = 30 + (.Height * (n - 1))
        .Left = NewLeft + 3
        .Width = NewWidth - 7.5
        .Caption = ""
    End With
Next
''''''''''''''''''''''


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ctrResizeWindow_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)
  xOffset = 0
    yOffset = 0
    ButtonResize = False

End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rem  ~~> All Items above this line are for the userform controls.... & _
                  Items Below are for this userforms controls:



Private Sub cmdCloseForm_Click()
        Unload Me
End Sub
```